# How to add dialup group?

Tags: users

I recently moved to Ubuntu earlier I was a Windows user so I know nothing about Ubuntu. I have installed wammu on my desktop but it doesn't work, says add dialup group.

How to I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) this will add `$USER` to the dialout group:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

---

`$USER` is the name you used to log in with (`echo $USER` on command line will show your name) so you can use that command 'as is' and do not need to change anything.

Comment: Thanx verry much for your help. It was verry useful for me Mr Rinzwind