# 3D Printing problem

Tags: 18.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Optiplex 390. I have a Prusa Mendel i3 3d printer, and have also installed Cura version 15.04.3 but I cannot get the computer to communicate with the printer.

It worked perfectly with Windows 10. I am using a USB AB cable connected to the circuit board of the printer. The printer is not an original Prusa machine but a clone.

When I enter `lsusb` in the terminal it says ; `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter` when using Cura 15.04.3 `the opening serial port` rectangle goes grayscale, when using RepRap, it says `Error opening port /dev/ttyUSB0: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your user does not yet have the permissions to use serial ports for communication. How to fix this:

1. Open a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> should do that.
2. Execute the following command to add your user to the `dialout` group of users:

   ```
   sudo adduser $USER dialout
   ```

   `$USER` is automatically evaluated to be the name you used to log in with, so you can use that command 'as is' and do not need to change anything.
3. Reboot the computer.

   This is needed if you configured automatic login for your user. If not, then logging out and in again (effectively restarting your graphical environment) would also be enough. In any case, once the command `groups` executed as your user in a terminal includes `dialout` in its output, the change was effective and you should now be able to access the serial USB device.

(This answer was adapted from [an answer by @Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/a/209542)).